# Using functional dependency to eliminate type parameter

Tags: haskell, parsec, functional-dependencies

I am trying to implement a Parsec `Stream` wrapper that will remember the last `uncons`'d token in order to provide some look-behind capability.  I want the wrapper to work with any `Stream` instance.  Here's what I have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module MStream where

import Text.Parsec
import Control.Monad ( liftM )

data MStream s t = MStream (Maybe t) s

instance Stream s m t => Stream (MStream s t) m t where
  uncons (MStream _ s) = fmap (\(t, s') -> (t, MStream (Just t) s')) `liftM` uncons s

getPrevToken :: Stream s m t => ParsecT (MStream s t) u m (Maybe t)
getPrevToken = (\(MStream t _) -> t) `liftM` getInput

mstream :: s -> MStream s t
mstream = MStream Nothing
```

This works, but I don't like having to carry the `t` parameter in the `MStream` type constructor.  Surely it should be sufficient to require only the `s` parameter, since `t` can be derived from `s` as long as there is a witness for `Stream s m t`.  I've tried using type families and GADTs, but I keep running into obscure errors about ambiguous type variables and unsatisfied functional dependencies.

Is there a way to remove `t` from the `MStream` type constructor so I don't have to write:

```
sillyParser :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT (MStream s Char) u m String
sillyParser = do
  t <- getPrevToken
  maybe (string "first") (\c -> string $ "last" ++ [c]) t
```

Comment: I tried to make `StreamDep s t | s -> t` superclass of `Stream` and use that: `data MStream s = forall t. StreamDep s t => MStream (Maybe t) (m ()) s`. Also `data MStream s = forall m t. Stream s m t => MStream (Maybe t) (m ()) s`. I'd say, not worth the pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this by moving the goalposts (somewhat):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

module MStream where

import Text.Parsec
import Control.Monad ( liftM )

class Stream s m t => MStream s m t | s -> t where
  getPrevToken :: ParsecT s u m (Maybe t)

data MStreamImpl s t = MStreamImpl (Maybe t) s

instance Stream s m t => MStream (MStreamImpl s t) m t where
  getPrevToken = (\(MStreamImpl t _) -> t) `liftM` getInput

instance Stream s m t => Stream (MStreamImpl s t) m t where
  uncons (MStreamImpl _ s) = fmap (\(t, s') -> (t, MStreamImpl (Just t) s')) `liftM` uncons s

mstream :: s -> MStreamImpl s t
mstream = MStreamImpl Nothing

sillyParser :: MStream s m Char => ParsecT s u m String
sillyParser = do
  t <- getPrevToken
  maybe (string "first") (\c -> string $ "last" ++ [c]) t
```

Instead of trying to remove the type parameter from `MStream`, I turned `MStream` into a typeclass, with a canonical instance `MStreamImpl`.  So now, the `sillyParser` type signature can be written in a more compact manner simply by replacing the `Stream` context with an `MStream` context.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module MStream where

import Control.Monad ( liftM )

-- Class so we don't need to carry `m` in `MStream` definition.
class StreamDep s t | s -> t where
class StreamDep s t => Stream s m t where
  uncons :: s -> m (Maybe (t, s))

data MStream s = forall t. StreamDep s t => MStream (Maybe t) s

data ParsecT s u m a = ParsecT s u (m a)
instance Monad m => Monad (ParsecT s u m) where

getInput :: ParsecT s u m s
getInput = undefined

instance StreamDep s t => StreamDep (MStream s) t where

instance (Monad m, Stream s m t) => Stream (MStream s) m t where
  uncons (MStream _ s) = fmap (\(t, s') -> (t, MStream (Just t) s')) `liftM` uncons s

getPrevToken :: (Monad m, Stream s m t) => ParsecT (MStream s) u m (Maybe t)
getPrevToken = (\(MStream t _) -> t) `liftM` getInput

mstream :: StreamDep s t => s -> MStream s
```

I get quite close, but get an error:

```
Pars.hs:28:35:
    Could not deduce (t1 ~ t)
    from the context (Monad m, Stream s m t)
      bound by the type signature for
                 getPrevToken :: (Monad m, Stream s m t) =>
                                 ParsecT (MStream s) u m (Maybe t)
      at Pars.hs:27:17-76
    or from (StreamDep s t1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 MStream :: forall s t. StreamDep s t => Maybe t -> s -> MStream s,
               in a lambda abstraction
```

Yet by using both contexts `Stream s m t` and `StreamDep s t1` it should be obvious that `(t ~ t1)`.

By using artillery, we can make it compile:

```
getPrevToken :: (Monad m, Stream s m t) => ParsecT (MStream s) u m (Maybe t)
getPrevToken = (\(MStream t _) -> unsafeCoerce t) `liftM` getInput
```

But I cannot try this, as it requires modification to `parsec`.